# Print only the first word in line

Tags: perl

I need some help with following perl code.

```
#!perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $file, '<', 'ubb' or die $1;

my $spool = 0;
my @matchingLines;

while (<$file>) {
    if (/GROUPS/i) {
        $spool = 1;
        next;
    }
    elsif (/SERVERS/i) {
        $spool = 0;
        print map { "$_" } @matchingLines;
        @matchingLines = ();
    }
    if ($spool) {
        push (@matchingLines, $_);
    }
}
close ($file);
```

Output from that is shown below.

```
ADM                     LMID=GW_S4_1_PM,GW_S4_2_BM
                        GRPNO=1

ADM_TMS                 LMID=GW_S4_1_PM,GW_S4_2_BM
                        GRPNO=2
                        TMSNAME=TMS

ADM_1                   LMID=GW_S4_1_PM
                        GRPNO=11

ADM_2                   LMID=GW_S4_2_BM
                        GRPNO=12

DMWSG_Gateway_1         LMID=GW_S4_1_PM
                        GRPNO=101
                        ENVFILE="../GW_S4.Gateway.envfile"

DMWSG_Gateway_2         LMID=GW_S4_2_BM
                        GRPNO=201
                        ENVFILE="../GW_S4.Gateway.envfile"

DMWSG_1                 LMID=GW_S4_1_PM
                        GRPNO=106

DMWSG_2                 LMID=GW_S4_2_BM
                        GRPNO=206
```

But I only would like to get the first word of each line (e.g. `ADM`, `ADM_TMS`, `ADM_1`).

Note that the file has a lot of other lines above and below what's printed here. I only want to do this for lines that is in between `GROUPS` and `SERVERS`.

Comment: `push (@matchingLines, $_) if $_ =~ m/^ADM/;`

Comment: please make your question next time from begin clear...

Comment: To be fair, I thought the question was pretty clear from the beginning, although there is space for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest 2 changes in your code

Note: Tested these with your sample data (plus other stuff) in your question.

### I: Extract first word before `push`

Change this

```
push (@matchingLines, $_);
```

to

```
push (@matchingLines, /^(\S+)/);
```

This would push the first word of each line into the array, instead of the entire line.

Note that `/^(\S+)/` is shorthand for `$_ =~ /^(\S+)/`. If you're using an explicit loop variable like in [7stud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852403/1743811), you can't use this shorthand, use the explicit syntax instead, say `$line =~ /^(\S+)/` or whatever your loop variable is.

Of course, you can also use `split` function as suggested in [7stud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852403/1743811).

### II: Change how you `print`

Change this

```
print map { "$_" } @matchingLines;
```

into

```
local $" = "\n";
print "@matchingLines \n";
```

`$"` specifies the delimiter used for list elements when the array is printed with `print` or `say` inside double quotes.

Alternatively, as per [TLP's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851910/print-only-the-first-word-in-line/17853159?noredirect=1#comment26066778_17853159),

```
$\ = $/; 
print for @lines;
```

or

```
print join("\n", @lines), "\n"
```

Note that `$/` is the input record separator (newline by default), `$\` is the output record separator (undefined by default). `$\` is appended after each `print` command.

For more information on `$/`, `$\`, and `$"`:

- See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (just use CTRL+F to find them in that page)
- Or you can simply use `perldoc -v '$/'` etc on your console to get those information.

### Note on readability

I don't think implicit regex matching i.e. `/pattern/` is bad per se.

But matching against a variable, i.e. `$variable =~ /pattern/` is more readable (as in you can immediately see there's a regex matching going on) and more beginner-friendly, at the cost of conciseness.

Comment: agree about the brackets, not sure if parenthesis needs to stay, not sure about bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, parens needed (I didn't seem them).  Bad practice for sure.  There's what's called "modern perl", and there's old style perl.  That is old style perl.

Comment: Why did you delete your comment, it looked like I'm talking to myself. Checking up on the bad practice part.

Comment: Sorry.  I saw the parens, deleted my comment to rewrite it, then you posted your comment.  For future searches, I started off the comments by suggesting a change to the regex, and I also stated that implicit regex matches are bad practice, which is why I rewrote the op's if statements.

Comment: Hi again, either am I blind or stupid (or both). But I don't get following to work.

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $file, '<', 'ubb' or die $1;

my $spool = 0;
my @matchingLines;

while (my $line = <$file>) {
    if ($line =~ /GROUPS/i) {
        $spool = 1;
        next;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /SERVERS/i) {
        $spool = 0;
        local $" = "\";
        print "@matchingLines \n";
        @matchingLines = ();
    }
    if ($spool) {
        push (@matchingLines, /^(\S+)/);
    }
}
close ($file);

Comment: @user2617541 can you define "not working"? (also pasting a lot of code in comment is not a good idea because it's hard to read)

Comment: Hi, I get
Array found where operator expected at mats line 18, at end of line
  (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 17)
        (Missing operator before ?)
Backslash found where operator expected at mats line 18, near "@matchingLines \"
        (Missing operator before \?)
String found where operator expected at mats line 18, at end of line
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at mats line 18, near "print "@matchingLines "
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at mats line 18.

Thanks for the tip not to paste code.

Comment: I noticed that you have `local $" = "\"` instead of `local $" = "\n"`. That would be problematic because it would cause an unclosed string (because you are escaping the double quote)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one (blind). But, 
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at mats line 22, <$file> line 70.

Comment: oh I see, you're combining both mine and 7stud's answer. In that case you have to replace `/^(\S+)/` with `$line =~ /^(\S+)/`

Comment: Line 22 is,
push (@matchingLines, /^(\S+)/);

Comment: glad to know that it works. Also please consider voting up / choose as "accepted" answers that you personally think are helpful. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: +1 for #1. As for #2, it might be more readable to actually do `print join("\n", @lines), "\n"`. Or `say for @lines`. Or perhaps `$\ = $/; print for @lines`.

Comment: @TLP, thanks. Included your suggestions on the `print` statement

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;    #say()

my $fname = 'data.txt';
open my $INFILE, '<', $fname 
    or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";  #-->Not $1"

my $recording_on = 0;
my @matching_lines;

for my $line (<$INFILE>) {

    if ($line =~ /groups/i) {
        $recording_on = 1;
        next;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /servers/i) {
        say for @matching_lines;  #say() is the same as print(), but it adds a newline at the end
        @matching_lines = ();
        $recording_on = 0;
    }

    if ($recording_on) {
        my ($first_word, $trash)  = split " ", $line, 2;
        push @matching_lines, $first_word;
    }
}

close $INFILE;
```

Comment: I was to quick with return,

Bareword "say" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at johan line 18.
Execution of johan aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: `use 5.014;`  or whatever version of perl you are using (above 5.010 I think) to import the say() function.  See the use statements at the top of the code.  I think you will find that print() is a pain in the ass, and you will use say() most of the time.

Comment: don't need the trash (no pun intended), you can simply write `my ($first_word) = ...`, the trash is simply discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flip-flop operator (range)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to select a part of your input. The idea of this operator is that it returns false until its LHS (left hand side) returns true, and after that it returns true until its RHS returns false, after which it is reset. It is somewhat like preserving a state.

Note that the edge lines are also included in the match, so we need to remove those. After that, use [doubleDown's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743811/doubledown) idea and push `/^(\S+)/` onto an array. The nice thing about using this with `push` is that the capture regex returns an empty list if it fails, and this gives us a warning-free failure when the regex does not match.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @matches;
while (<>) {
    if (/GROUPS/i .. /SERVERS/i) {    # flip-flop remembers the matches
        next if (/GROUPS/i or /SERVERS/i);
        push @matches, /^(\S+)/;
    }
}

# @matches should now contain the first words of those lines
```